# Why is my C code not printing anything from the else if statements?

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C and I fail to see what's wrong. It outputs the month but nothing else.

I'm trying to get something that transforms from a mm/dd/yyyy format to a written one. I'm doing the days part and so far been unsuccessful. It prints the corresponding month but not the day. I'm trying to keep it simple and stick to what I've been studying so far such as switch cases and else-if statements, I know it'd be more efficient with a for loop or something but it's not what I'm aiming for, please keep it simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;

    printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year);

    if (day == 1 || day == 11 || day == 21 || day == 31)
    {
        printf(&day, "st");
    }
    else if (day == 2 || day == 12 || day == 22)
    {
        printf(&day, "nd");
    }
    else if (day == 3 || day == 13 || day == 23)
    {
        printf(&day, "rd");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(&day, "th");
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop ignoring warnings, they're there for a reason! Your compiler output is most likely screaming to you about the problem. Are you able to find/see it?

Comment: `printf(&day, "st");` makes no sense. It should be more like `printf("%dst", day);`

Comment: As a general guideline for further questions: Whenever you are dealing with any input, you should also include the exact input (with all spaces, commas, etc.), the output and the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;

    printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year);

    if (day == 1 || day == 11 || day == 21 || day == 31)
    {
        printf("%dst",day);
    }
    else if (day == 2 || day == 12 || day == 22)
    {
        printf("%dnd",day);
    }  
    else if (day == 3 || day == 13 || day == 23)
    {
        printf("%drd",day);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%dth",day);
    }
}
```

> I think from this code may solved your doubt.
> but,at the time of input enter:'03/15/2023' not 03 15 2023

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a pretty good answer, but it would be even better if you'd explain *why* it solves the problem. In fact, I'd say that you probably don't need to reproduce the OP's entire code -- just one of the `printf()` statements with correct syntax would illustrate the issue and help the OP learn how to use that function.

Comment: Note that 11th, 12th and 13th don’t follow the rules that 1st, 21st, 31st, 2nd, 22nd, 3rd and 23rd follow.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler ,i try to resolve this issue

Answer (score -1):

You must specify the format to printf as its first argument.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int month, day, year;

        printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year);

        if (day == 1 || day == 11 || day == 21 || day == 31)
        {
                printf("%d %s", day, "st");
        }
        else if (day == 2 || day == 12 || day == 22)
        {
                printf("%d %s", day, "nd");
        }
        else if (day == 3 || day == 13 || day == 23)
        {
                printf("%d %s", day, "rd");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("%d %s", day, "th");
        }
}
```

Comment: Why (for example) `printf("%d %s", day, "st");` instead of `printf("%d st", day);`?

Comment: Because (I think) it is the closest to the OP code and intend. There are a lot of improvements left as an exercise :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the code you looking for

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int month, day, year;
        printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year);
        if (day == 1 || day == 11 || day == 21 || day == 31)
        {
            printf("%dst ",day);
        }
        else if (day == 2 || day == 12 || day == 22)
        {
            printf( "%dnd ",day);
        }
        else if (day == 3 || day == 13 || day == 23)
        {
            printf("%drd ",day);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%dth ",day);
        }
        switch(month){
            case 1:
            printf("January ");
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("Febraury ");
            break;
            case 3:
            printf("March ");
            break;
            case 4:
            printf("April ");
            break;
            case 5:
            printf("May ");
            break;
            case 6:
            printf("June ");
            break;
            case 7:
            printf("July ");
            break;
            case 8:
            printf("August ");
            break;
            case 9:
            printf("September ");
            break;
            case 10:
            printf("Octomber ");
            break;
            case 11:
            printf("November ");
            break;
            case 12:
            printf("December ");
            break;
        }
        printf("%d",year);
        
    }
```

Mistakes in your code on my point of view

1. scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year); - this scanf only read day and month if the inputs are separated by '/' EX: 3/15/2023
2. printf(&day, "st"); - the syntax of printf is wrong

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chKqp.png)

Comment: More mistakes: `11`, `12` and `13` should be used with `th` and not with `st`, `nd` or `rd`. Also, note the spellings of `October` and `February`

Comment: Also strongly suggest checking the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: yeah you are right I just need to tell the major things

Comment: The question explicitely mentions "mm/dd/yyyy" format. Therefore that is most likely not a mistake in the code.